# Should I ignore $0$ when do inverse transform sampling?

Tags: monte-carlo, sampling

Generic method

1. Generate $U \sim \mathrm{Uniform}(0,1)$.
2. Return $F^{-1}(U)$.

So, in step 1, $U$ has domain/support as $[0,1]$, so it is possible that $U=0$ or $U=1$,
but $F^{-1}(0)=-\infty$. Should I reject the value $U=0$ and $U=1$ before applying step 2?

For example, discrete distribution sampling: $X$ takes on values $x_1, x_2, x_3$ with probability $p_1,p_2,p_3$

1. Generate $U \sim \mathrm{Uniform}(0,1)$.
2. Find the smallest $k$ such that $F(x_k)\geq U$  ($F$ is the CDF).

However, if $U=0$, and $p_1=0$, $k$ would be $1$. It could generate $x_1$ though its probability $p_1=0$. Is it acceptable?

Comment: If $U$ is generated as a sample of a random variable uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$, then $0$ and $1$ can't be values returned, can they?  As a practical matter, congruential random number generators don't return a value of $0$ at all. I don't recall off the top of my head if it is possible for them to return $1$, but I suspect the answer is No there too.

Comment: @DilipSarwate: All linear congruential PRNGs I have seen are actually _affine_ congruential and will generate $0$ just fine. Commonly, generators of "equidistributed between $0$ and $1$" random numbers actually produce something like $a\cdot 2^{-53}$ where $a$ is an integer equidistributed in $0\le a<2^{53}$, so they can return $0$ but $1$ exactly.

Comment: The results $0$ and $1$ occur with negligible probability. So as a practical fact, it doesn't matter what you choose to do.

Comment: @André Nicolas: however, in a program, when Random.next() generates values [0,1), if it happens to output 0... the whole program I build upon the sampling algorithm would crash.

Comment: @By "it doesn't matter" I meant that there is negligible potential error in the simulation. But there may be very good programming reasons not to allow $0$. The only potential issue is that a numerical procedure that crashes at $0$ may be unreliable *near* $0$, which is a much more serious matter.

Comment: @HenningMakholm  Yes, my mistake. I was thinking about pseudorandom _linear feedback shift registers_ for which the state is always nonzero (unless it is "seeded" with all zeros and thus stays in that state forever) but writing about linear congruential generators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, it doesn't matter: the event $U=0$ occurs with probability $0$, and can thus be ignored.  (In probabilistic jargon, it [almost never](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely) happens.)

In practice, it's possible that your PRNG may return a value that is exactly $0$.  For a reasonably good PRNG, this is unlikely, but it may not be quite unlikely enough for you to bet that it never happens.  Thus, if your program would crash on $U=0$, a prudent programmer should check for that event and generate a new random number if it occurs.

(Note that many PRNG routines are defined to return values in the range $0 \le U < 1$: for example, the [Java default PRNG](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextDouble%28%29) is defined to return values of the form $m\cdot2^{-53}$ for $m \in \{0,1,\dotsc,2^{53}-1\}$.  If you're using such a PRNG, a cheap but effective way to avoid the case $U=0$ is to use the number $1-U$ instead of $U$.)